# http basic authentication error in symfony

Tags: apache, symfony, fastcgi, basic-authentication

In my project (a web API) done with Symfony 2.2 I have set http basic authentication. It works ok locally (tested in windows last XAMPP stable release and mysql db in a local mac with Lion), so I think it's not a password encoding issue.
We have a managed server with a couple of versions of php installed. PHPinfo in our app dir says 5.4.16 with CGI/FastCGI. We are only allowed to change parameters through .htaccess
We have it for now in a subdir of our main site as http://oursite.com/projectName/symfonyDirsHere(app, web, etc...)

In dev.log:
security.INFO: Authentication exception occurred; redirecting to authentication entry point (A Token was not found in the SecurityContext.) [] []
So I suspect is fastcgi problem not passing authorization parameters as it's explained in src/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/ServerBag.php
but I can't make it work, maybe because I'm not in a root domain directory with a redirect to /web?
I don't see anything about mod-rewrite at phpinfo. Maybe it's not enabled?

My htaccess:

```
DirectoryIndex app.php
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
    RewriteRule ^app\.php(/(.*)|$) %{CONTEXT_PREFIX}/$2 [R=301,L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
    RewriteRule .? - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$1 ^(/.+)(.+)::\2$
    RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=BASE:%1]
    RewriteRule .? %{ENV:BASE}app.php [L]
#Esto por el tema del fastcgi en apache
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} ^(.+)$
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
SetEnv TZ Europe/Madrid
</IfModule>
<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_alias.c>
        RedirectMatch 302 ^/$ /app.php/
    </IfModule>
</IfModule>
```

I'll appreciate any help/suggestions/ideas to solve the problem. Thank you in advance

Comment: php version `5.14.16`, are you sure?? :)

Comment: Yes, it was released 6 of June http://php.net/archive/2013.php#id2013-06-06-2

Comment: In this case this is the `5.4.16` not the `5.14.16`! That said, I don't think this is the issue your are having...

Comment: Yes, sorry, didn't realize it was a typo, too many hours browsing for answers. Thanks for reading.